# Add values in column based on condition in Python

Tags: python, pandas

```
Source_No  Parent   Type    Amt
123         123     Tail    100
456         123     Coll    100
789         123     Coll    100
```

I want the code to create a new column a new column 'Tot_Amt' which will add the Amt of all Source_No, where Parent = Source_No and for other

Expected output.

```
Source No  Parent   Type    Amt     Tot_Amt
123         123     Parent   100     200
456         123     Child    100      0
789         123     Child    100      0
```

Comment: Is `Source_No` a unique value for each row? Can two rows have the same `Source_No`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is groupby, aggregate, and then merge back based on your `Parent = Source_No` constraint

```
# group by parent all the non-parent rows (SourceNo != Parent)
grouped = df.loc[df.SourceNo != df.Parent].groupby(df.Parent)

# sum the Amt for each group
summed = grouped.Amt.agg(Tot_Amt='sum')

# merge with the original frame on SouceNo == Parent
df = df.merge(summed, left_on='SourceNo', right_on='Parent', how='left')
df.Tot_Amt.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Will give you this result:

```
   SourceNo  Parent    Type  Amt  Tot_Amt
0       123     123  Parent  100    200.0
1       456     123   Child  100      0.0
2       789     123   Child  100      0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
df["Tot_Amt"] = (df.groupby(["Parent"])["Amt"].sum() - df.groupby(["Source_No"])["Amt"].sum()).fillna(0).reset_index(drop=True)
```